# Filtering data compared to another table without a join

Tags: mysql, sql

This query:

```
select a.* , u.firstn, u.lastn,  u.Extension
from jfi.ambitiontempdata a
inner join jackson_id.users u
on a.Extension = u.Extension;
```

Pulls up a lot of records I've created for a CSR call system showing call records, the number called and the number that initiated the call, etc.

This works great, but I need to filter it one more time by another piece of data.

I have a table called `jfi.ambition_customer_data` which doesn't have an ID or anything to join it in my existing query. However, I need to run the above query and check the `jfi.ambition_customer_data` table to see if certain phone numbers exist in each table. The number that I check from my `jfi.ambitiontempdata` table depends on two factors though.

From the query above, if `a.outbound = 1` then check if `called_party` exists in `jfi.ambition_customer_data`, and if `a.outbound = 0` then check to see if `calling_party` exists.

Here's a screenshot of my results for reference:

[image]

Here is data from the customer table, so the above call fields need to be compared to 'Phone' in this table:

[image]

So how can I filter my select data to make sure that I only get records where the 2 different numbers may exist in the customer table depending on the call type?

Comment: It will be great, if you provide data of `customer table` because your question is solely based on this table and without seeing data it's not good to make a wild guess.

Comment: Sorry, just added customer data and a brief explaination of the comparison that needs to be made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple union will suffice, I think, and is probably easier to understand:

```
select a.* FROM ambitiontempdata a
inner join customer c on a.called_party = c.phone
where a.outbound = 1
UNION
select a.* FROM ambitiontempdata a
inner join customer c on a.calling_party = c.phone
where a.outbound = 0;
```

EDIT

To combine this simply with your own query you can do:

```
select a.* , u.firstn, u.lastn,  u.Extension
from jfi.ambitiontempdata a
inner join jackson_id.users u
on a.Extension = u.Extension
inner join jfi.ambition_customer_data c
on a.called_party = c.phone 
where a.outbound = 1
UNION
select a.* , u.firstn, u.lastn,  u.Extension
from jfi.ambitiontempdata a
inner join jackson_id.users u
on a.Extension = u.Extension
inner join jfi.ambition_customer_data c
on a.calling_party = c.phone 
where a.outbound = 0;
```

SECOND EDIT

Is this any better?

```
SELECT ua.*, u.firstn, u.lastn,  u.Extension
FROM
(select a.* FROM ambitiontempdata a
inner join customer c on a.called_party = c.phone
where a.outbound = 1
UNION
select a.* FROM ambitiontempdata a
inner join customer c on a.calling_party = c.phone
where a.outbound = 0) ua 
INNER JOIN jackson_id.users u
on ua.Extension = u.Extension
```

Comment: I think I like this solution, but I'm a bit confused on how to fit this into the rest of my query (joins, extensions,etc.)

Comment: @TomN. Please see my edit.  It shows how you can combine with your existing query.  The alternative is to use a cte (depending on MySQL version).  Please note I haven't tested the edit as I do not have the tables!

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense! Just ran it, thanks for the help!

Comment: @TomN. My pleasure.  Glad to have helped

Comment: Sorry, actually I have one quick question. I ran the original and it runs fine and returns about 2700 rows, as expected. However, when I run the combined version it keeps timing the connection out, even after raising my timeout limit in MySQL workbench. Is there any other way to append the first name, last name and extension on to my statement where the extensions match in the u and a tables?

Comment: @TomN. Can you use cte?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty green with a lot of this so I'm not even sure exactly what that would consist of, but I'm using mysql workbench and I have admin privileges

Comment: @TomN. Which version MySQL?

Comment: 5.6.30 is my current version

Comment: And the core union clause works perfectly, I just have to have the names and extension appended

Comment: @TomN. Sorry.  I am not quite sure what you mean.  Does my Edited version run?  If so, what would you like to add?

Comment: Sorry, the original union runs perfectly and returns around 2700 rows. The edited version that includes the names and extensions times out my connection every time, even after increasing the timeout period

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154353/discussion-between-jonathan-willcock-and-tom-n).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  a.* , u.firstn, u.lastn,  u.Extension
  IF(a.outbound = 1,
     (select phone from jfi.ambition_customer_data where customerNumber = a.calling_party),
     (select phone from jfi.ambition_customer_data where customerNumber = a.called_party)
    )
From jfi.ambitiontempdata a
INNER JOIN jackson_id.users u
ON a.Extension = u.Extension;
```

Comment: I think I understand this but just make sure I'm clear: if the customer table has only one phone number column, ```phone``` which can house the number from either called_party or calling_party, but it's being determined by the outbound value, how am I going to equate called_party or calling_party to phone?

Comment: So I'd be selecting phone from jfi.ambition_customer_data where called_party exists if outbound = 1 and where calling_party exists if outbound = 0

Comment: I believe so, I'm just not used to some of the syntax. So is that IF statement saying if outbound = 1 run the first condition, else run the second condition?

Comment: Yes it is. @TomN.